# Align divs of unknown size

Tags: html, css

I want to align two divs like so:

```
      __________
______| Title  |__________________________________
|     |________|                                 |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|                    Box                         |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|                                                |
|________________________________________________|
```

I have been able to center the box div in the middle of the screen like I want, however I have only been able to get the title in the right spot with absolute pixel values. The problem I have is that the box div will have to change size depending on its contents and also if I use absolute pixel values it will be problematic to make it work with different screen resolutions. Is there any way to get the title div to align with the box div without using absolute pixel values?

Here is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./inst.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body id="bkg">
        <div id="cntr">
            <div id="title">test</div>
            <div id = "box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#box
{
width:40%;
height:30%;
background-color:white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #0C0C0F;
border-radius:10px;
border:2px solid black;
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}

#title {
background-color:white;
border-radius:10px;
border:2px solid black;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `#title` inside `#box`, then the position of `#title` will always be relative to that of `#box`.

Then, use these styles on `#title`:

```
position: relative;
top: -12px;
left: 10px;
```

This `#title` up and to the left of its original position.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Xus2c/.

Comment: Your's works pretty well, except that the title box extends all the way to the right. Do you have any suggestions to avoid this besides giving it a set size or right offset?

Comment: Yes - specify a width for the title, or make it an inline element (like a span, as I've done in the JS fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#box
{
background-color:white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #0C0C0F;
border-radius:10px;
border:2px solid black;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#title {
background-color:white;
border-radius:10px;
border:2px solid black;
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 10%;
z-index: 2;
padding:5px;
}
#cntr {
width:40%;
height:30%;
position: absolute;
margin:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I just noticed I left the wrong css code. I just updated it.